# when do I need to add member definitions to my class in scala?

Tags: scala, syntax

Im kinda new to scala, and I came up with this code when trying to learn match case syntax, the first code is what I did with its error, and the second is how I fixed it.
does anybody have a clue why do I need to add member "name" to my class?

```scala
trait T
class A (name: String) extends T
case class B (cls: A)
object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        val a: A = new A("John")
        val b: B = new B(a)
        checkType(b)
    }

    def checkType(cls: AnyRef) {
        cls match {

            case B(input) => println("your name is " + input.name)
            case _ => println("others")
        }
    }
}
```

the above code gives me the error :"value name is not a member of A"
now if i change the class A to this:

```
class A (n: String) extends T
{
   var name: String = n
}
```

the output will be "your name is John" (which is what I would expect)

P.S: if I change class A to case class, the problem is solved, why tho?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scala
class A (name: String) extends T
```

parameters without `val` or `var` are of type `private [this]` and are visible only within the class

if you change it to

```scala
class A (val name: String) extends T
```

this makes constructor parameter `name` public and can be accessible with class objects without need of a getter (use `var` if you want to change the values)

and if its this

```scala
case class A (name: String) extends T
```

case class parameters are public `val` by default so thats why it worked as you said

reference-
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/classes.html
https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/case-classes.html